# Why cannot I hide a div with v-if?

Tags: vue.js, web

Scenario: I have two options for a signup page. In the second one, I have a few more input elements and I only want to render that div when I click the second checkbox. For that, I wrote a v-if and it does not work properly.

(the project is in Vue)

```
<v-checkbox v-model="checkboxes" label="Bireysel Üyelik" value="checkbox-1"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox v-model="checkboxes" label="Kurumsal Üyelik" value="checkbox-2"></v-checkbox>
```

```
<div v-if="checkboxes === 'checkbox2'">
            <v-text-field
              name="cellPhone"
              label="Cep Telefonu"
              type="text"
              key="cell-phone"
              outlined
              dense
              required
            >
           </v-text-field>
</div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      checkboxes: "",
      }
   }
```

The Html and JS files are as above. The data is dynamically changed in the Vue instance and there is no problem with that. The problem is with the conditional rendering mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your checkbox you bind a value of checkbox-2

```
<v-checkbox v-model="checkboxes" label="Kurumsal Üyelik" value="checkbox-2"></v-checkbox>
```

but then you look for checkbox2

```
<div v-if="checkboxes === 'checkbox2'">
            <v-text-field
              name="cellPhone"
              label="Cep Telefonu"
              type="text"
              key="cell-phone"
              outlined
              dense
              required
            >
           </v-text-field>
```

change it to:

```
<div v-if="checkboxes === 'checkbox-2'">
            <v-text-field
              name="cellPhone"
              label="Cep Telefonu"
              type="text"
              key="cell-phone"
              outlined
              dense
              required
            >
           </v-text-field>
```

and it will work :) .

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't get what you mean precisely. When I click on checkbox-2, it updates checkboxes prop and I built my v-if on that. If checkboxes prop equals to checkbox-2, show my div on the page. What is wrong with that?

Comment: That's so funny. After hours of work you get blind and cannot see the - that you need :)